# Nodejs: Transport stream is not pumping data out completely?

Tags: node.js, stream

I was trying to learn the streaming in Nodejs by writing a small script. But after executing this one the last stream is not pushing all the data.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

function Newliner () {
    stream.Transform.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Newliner, stream.Transform);


Newliner.prototype._transform = function(chunk, enc, done)  {
    var split = 0;
    for( var i =0; i <chunk.length; i++){
    if(chunk[i] == 10) {
        this.push(chunk.slice(split,i));
        split = i+1;
    }
    }
}

function Greper(options) {
    stream.Transform.call(this);
    this.regex = new RegExp(options);
}
util.inherits(Greper, stream.Transform);


Greper.prototype._transform = function(chunk, enc, done)  {
    this.push(chunk);  //Even this is not working.
    /*
    var a = chunk.toString();
    if(this.regex.test(a)){ 
    this.push(chunk);
    }
    */
}



var n = new Newliner();
var g = new Greper("line");
var f = fs.createReadStream('a.txt');

f.pipe(n).pipe(g).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Input file a.txt is,

```
This is line one.
Another line.
Third line.
```

While executing only one line is displayed. What is the reason for this?

```
$ node test.js 
This is line one.
```

Note: When i am piping the File read stream directely to the 'g' it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the callback of the `_transform()` function when you are done processing the chunk. From [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback):

> `callback` (Function) Call this function (optionally with an error argument) when you are done processing the supplied chunk.

No more data will be pushed into the stream until the callback is called. If you don't call it, then the chunk will not be considered as processed… which is why your program stops after processing only one line.

Just add:

```
done();
```

at the end of the `Newliner.prototype._transform` and `Greper.prototype._transform` functions.

Comment: It worked after calling the done(). Thank you very much Paul.